# jQuery AJAX 200 status, yet mysterious syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a status 200 being returned when I'm using jQuery AJAX. However, I am also getting a syntax error from somewhere. I am posting to PHP like this:

```
function submit_order(orderInformation) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'queries/submit_order.php?<?=time();?>',
        data: 'orderInformation=' + JSON.stringify(orderInformation),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData);
            $('#content_container').fadeOut(340, function () {
                var new_content = $('#content_container').clone(false);
                $('#content_container').remove();
                new_content.css('display', 'none');
                new_content.children().remove();

                new_content.appendTo('body');
                $('#content_container').vkTemplate('templates/confirm_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', returnedData, function (el, data, context) {
                console.log('success'); 

                    $('#content_container').fadeIn(340);
                });
            });
        },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
      }
    });
}
```

My PHP code is pretty straightforward:

```
$order_information = json_decode($json_str, true);

//go through the array and make an email out of it
//add a few elements to the array
//send the email

//send back a json string with the added elements
echo json_encode($order_information);
```

Yet I get this:

[image: error screenshot]

And oddly, if I copy paste the JSON string from `console.log(JSON.stringify(orderInformation))` into the PHP page:

```
$json_str = '{"sector_0":{"file":[],"sector_info":{"sector_label":"NIO","purchase_order":"test","proof":false},"lines":{"line_0":{"description":"test","quantity":"2","productId":"1","addressId":"20","shipViaId":"1","notes":false}}}} ';
```

everything works. What is this error? Where could this `<` seen in the error be coming from?

Thanks

Comment: 200 is not an error. It's an OK response from the webserver.

Comment: Did you try to open `queries/submit_order.php?<?=time();?>` in a browser or check with firebug what is exactly returned by a server? Looks like you have a syntax error or something, and html is returned

Comment: @Codeguy007 then why is printing it to the log being triggered on the `error` callback? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you omit the <?=time();?>

Comment: @KingKongFrog no difference

Comment: @thomas It is error callback as you do not get valid json back

Comment: Install firebug on your firefox or any tool that can show you raw request responses on your browser and check what is returned by server

Comment: <?=time();?> definitely doesn't work as you can't run php clientside.

Comment: @Codeguy007 thanks. corrected that. didn't mean that 200 was the error. the error callback shows the status code of 200 and shows an error

Comment: @Codeguy007 <?=time()?> is not run on the client side. it is run by the server and output on the client

Comment: No it's not. It's in your javascript so it's clientside.

Comment: just replace <?=time()?> with a javascript equivalent.

Comment: @Codeguy007 looks like this when viewing the javascrpt `url: 'queries/submit_order.php?1355423356',`

Comment: Sorry you are right. It will be rendered on page load by php if the javascript is inline or run through php.

Comment: @thomas This is obviously your service that is returning a bad JSON string. You probably will need to show us that code to get this fixed.

Comment: So did check what is returned by your server? Raw response.

Comment: @E_p yes, I found where the `<` is coming from. The string php is returning `<br /> <b>Warning</b>: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/public_html/bch/queries/submit_order.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />`. Like the string php is getting is malformed or null or something. but the string javascript is giving it checks out on jsonlint.com..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your error handler that gets fired and logs:

- xhr.status (200)
- thrownError (the syntax error)

Note that `$.ajax` with `dataType: json` will fire the error handler even if the server returns `200 OK` but the response is invalid JSON. The syntax error is not in your JavaScript code but in the JSON. Identify where the `<` is coming from and make sure that your PHP script is sending valid JSON.

Tip: open the console and look at the network tab; all XHRs are logged there along with headers and body.

Comment: thank you. I found out that the syntax error is coming from php printing out `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/public_html/bch/queries/submit_order.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />` So, thus the `<`. I can't understand what is wrong with the foreach loop however `foreach ( $order_information as $sector_index => &$sector_value ){`

Comment: It is a PHP question then :) You could post it as another question or  ninja-edit your question. PS: highly likely that `$order_information` is not an array.

Comment: PHP was adding slashes to the string :/ `stripslashes` cured it. Does it always do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

200 - Is an Ok response by a server `http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html`

You have a syntax error in your response server returns invalid json

As your PHP code seams fine, there must be something else. Syntax error or your framework returns json wrapped in html ...

Use proper tools to see what is returned by server. (firebug on firefox/ developer tools on chrome)

In your image you see `0: "<"` That means that returned string starts with `<` - That means it is html that got returned.

Looks like you use chrome. Go to your "network" tab in chrome an you should be able to see raw response for your request.

so it is a php error:

`$sector_index`  is not itarable. Can you var_dump it to see. what it is?

Comment: Now check that is in your $sector_index. As php does not know how to iterate through it

Comment: PHP was for some reason adding slashes to the JSON string it was receiving. I don't know if that's something it always does, but stripslashes seems to have fixed it.. Thank you for walking me through this :)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like `<?=time()?>` isn't getting processed. Alert the URL before you post to it for verification.