# Ajax request return 200 OK but error instead of success

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me..

i have this AJAX script calling a XML page.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "game/",
    dataType: "xml",
    data : {
        g : 'new',
        uid : uid
    },

    error: function (xml) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(xml);

    alert(xml.status + ' ' + xml.statusText)
  },


    success: function(xml)
    {
    ...

    }
```

But i return status: 200 OK in the error object. Why is that happen?

Here i my console log:

```
ERROR speedywebs.js:678
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}abort: function (e){var t=e||S;return f&&f.abort(t),N(0,t),this}always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}complete: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}done: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}error: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}fail: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return w===2?o:null}getResponseHeader: function (e){var t;if(w===2){if(!l){l={};while(t=Sn.exec(o))l[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=l[e.toLowerCase()]}return t==null?null:t}overrideMimeType: function (e){return w||(c.mimeType=e),this}pipe: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,s){var o=s[0],u=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[s[1]](function(){var e=u&&u.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[o+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,u?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}progress: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}promise: function (e){return e!=null?b.extend(e,r):r}readyState: 4responseText: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cards><card1><id>119</id><download>19.99</download><upload>12.48</upload><ping>24</ping><testserver>Stockholm 2</testserver><hostname>x1-6-28-c6-8e-96-b1-da.cpe.webspeed.dk</hostname><name>@risager</name><location>Vangede</location><connection>Kabel / Fiber</connection><comment></comment></card1><card2><id>171</id><download>-</download><upload>-</upload><ping>-</ping><testserver>Stockholm 2</testserver><hostname>94.191.184.222.mobile.3.dk</hostname><name>@camillaBandit</name><location>København K</location><connection>4G/LTE</connection><comment>Inde hos Joe & The Juice</comment></card2></cards>"setRequestHeader: function (e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return w||(e=y[n]=y[n]||e,g[e]=t),this}state: function (){return n}status: 200statusCode: function (e){var t;if(e)if(w<2)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else x.always(e[x.status]);return this}statusText: "OK"success: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);r==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&r!=="string"&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?s=a.length:r&&(u=t,l(r))}return this}then: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,s){var o=s[0],u=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[s[1]](function(){var e=u&&u.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[o+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,u?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}__proto__: Object
```

The XML response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cards><card1><id>119</id><download>19.99</download><upload>12.48</upload><ping>24</ping><testserver>Stockholm 2</testserver><hostname>x1-6-28-c6-8e-96-b1-da.cpe.webspeed.dk</hostname><name>@risager</name><location>Vangede</location><connection>Kabel / Fiber</connection><comment></comment></card1><card2><id>171</id><download>-</download><upload>-</upload><ping>-</ping><testserver>Stockholm 2</testserver><hostname>94.191.184.222.mobile.3.dk</hostname><name>@camillaBandit</name><location>København K</location><connection>4G/LTE</connection><comment>Inde hos Joe & The Juice</comment></card2></cards>
```

Comment: What did the 3rd parameter of the error callback contain? parseerror?

Comment: Just a side comment, maybe add a "complete" callback as well and check out the textStatus of the complete callback.  Other than that, you have a pretty odd case :(

Comment: your xml is invalid. `<comment>Inde hos Joe &...` should be `<comment>Inde hos Joe &amp;...` or wrap the strings in CDATA.

Comment: Something similar happened to me when I got invalid json, probably your xml is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is XML parsing issue. The XML you receive has unescaped ampersand character in line 25:
`<comment>Inde hos Joe & The Juice</comment>`

Ask the client to [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml) or change it to text. The rest of the XML parses correctly.

Please check a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success)

Also, please remember to add such info to your question next time, it helps a lot. ;)

Comment: note, the response text is in his question, in the middle of that giant error log.

Comment: There, i pulled the xml out of the dump to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of callback to see proper error.

```
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
      }
```

And then fix , by setting proper return data type.

This link might be helpful - [jQuery AJAX 200 status, yet mysterious syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866063/jquery-ajax-200-status-yet-mysterious-syntax-error)